# Alias service environment var in a Docker container

Tags: docker, environment-variables, docker-compose

I use Docker Compose to spin up my containers. I have a RethinkDB service container that exposes (amongst others) the host port in the following env var: `APP_RETHINKDB_1_PORT_28015_TCP_ADDR`.

However, my app must receive this host as an env var named `RETHINKDB_HOST`.

My question is: how can I alias the given env var to the desired one when starting the container (preferably in the most Dockerish way)? I tried:

```
env_file: .env
environment:
  - RETHINKDB_HOST=$APP_RETHINKDB_1_PORT_28015_TCP_ADDR
```

but first, it doesn't work and second, it doesn't look as if it's the best way to go.

Comment: if your app can use a startup script you can make the assignment in that script.  what i mean is the entrypoint for your app can be, for example /start. /start does your assignment and then execs your app.  It's a good question, i don't think there is a way to do it in the compose.yaml.

Comment: I thought about this, but I really don't like the approach.

Comment: The script probably is the best approach, though. The environment from links is set up after the other environment variables, so you can't reference links that way. Unless you want to alter RethinkDB to use Compose-friendly environment variable names, you're limited in options.

Comment: I understand. Thanks for the technical detail @kojiro. Hope this will be addressed in some way in the near future.

Comment: What about using a .env file that uses `RETHINKDB_HOST=$APP_RETHINKDB_1_PORT_28015_TCP_ADDR`

Comment: @Michael, it doesn't work, it prints the string as is.

Comment: you might have to evaluate your .env file if your app is not already.

Comment: Related [Docker Compose issue #1287: _Allow ENV variables in docker-compose.yml_](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/1287).

Comment: @kojiro, indeed, but it will be pretty hard to determine where were those env vars set (which container) in order to be available (as you said in your previous comment).

Answer (score 0):

When one container is linked to another, it sets the environment variable, but also a host entry. For example,

```
ubuntu:
    links:
        rethinkdb:rethinkdb
```

will allow ubuntu to `ping rethinkdb` and have it resolve the IP address. This would allow you to set `RETHINKDB_HOST=rethinkdb`. This won't work if you are relying on that variable for the port, however, but that's the only thing I can think of besides adding a startup script or modifying your `CMD`.

If you want to modify your `CMD`, which is currently set to `command: service rethink start`, for example, just change it to prepend the variable assignment, e.g.

```
command: sh -c 'RETHINKDB_HOST=$APP_RETHINKDB_1_PORT_28015_TCP_ADDR && service rethink start'
```

The approach would be similar if you are using  a startup script, you would just add that variable assignment as a line before the service starts

Comment: And will the `$APP_RETHINKDB_1_PORT_28015_TCP_ADDR` be there already if I follow your suggestion?

Comment: You said that your RethinkDB service container "exposes" the env var `APP_RETHINKDB_1_PORT_28015_TCP_ADDR`. Does that mean it is available/set once the container is running? That variable appears to be the result of a link to the rethinkdb container. If that is the case, yes, it would be already there when the `command` tries to use it. 
The difference between `RUN` instructions and the `CMD` instruction is that `CMD` happens at run time, while `RUN` happens during the build. Consequently, env variables and linked hostnames are available to `CMD` where they wouldn't work in `RUN`

Comment: btw :rethinkdb is redundant

Answer (score 0):

The environment variable name `APP_RETHINKDB_1_PORT_28015_TCP_ADDR` you are trying to use already contains the port number. It is already kind of "hard coded". I think you simply have to use this

```
environment:
  - RETHINKDB_HOST=28015
```